# can't edit css style sheet on wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I can't get a simple CSS change on my wordpress theme

I have SASS processed by gulp.js with browser-sync into a style.css file in the root of my theme folder.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: green;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2.6em;
    color: blue;
}
```

on my wordpress theme, I have H1 and H2 tags populated on the page

[image]

WP-content folder structure looks like this on PHPstorm

[image]

I have the theme selected under the wordpress admin, am I simply not referencing my  style.css file in my theme somehow? Or perhaps need to specify this in index.php / index.html?

**EDIT**

it works fine now, I had enqueue styles correct the first time not sure why it didn't work earlier

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the stylesheet in head, the default style.css should be enqueued in the functions.php using the function below.

`wp_enqueue_style( 'text-domain-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`

if this is done. Simply clear your cache or use private browsing or make sure no style is overriding your style updates below.(css hierarchy)

Answer (score 2):

you can import it in the style.css file in editor by placing it in the same theme css area for example location is E:\XAMPP\htdocs\project-example\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\css

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to include your stylesheet in the header.php file.

See: [How to include styles.css in wordpress theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391400/how-to-include-styles-css-in-wordpress-theme)